# how to download telugu news paper from web in android programmatically?

Tags: android, web-scraping, rss, feed

I want to download telugu news paper from my application and after download that one i have read in off line mode that one. how to implement that one please help me.
Thanku

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to find websites that provide free RSS feeds for Telgu news.
2. Then you need to write a parser of your choice in your app for parsing data from those RSS feeds.
3. Save the parsed data in a File and save it on your device(Internal/SD Card).
4. Also there will be images associated with the news item, so also save them.
5. Implement your UI as you like.
6. Finally render your news items from your device i.e. in Offline mode.